# JavaScript reference error can't find variable plus closure blues

Tags: javascript, variables, closures, box2d

Just in general I'm getting some errors with this.
The major one is in safari and the android browser get the error

> JavaScript reference error can't find variable

The variable in question is `b2AABB`.

Here is the code `var worldAABB = new b2AABB();`
I am working with *box2d JavaScript (the pixel lab variant) for google closure*. Also if you can give my closure dependencies and requires a good once over I would appreciate it.

```
<html>
<title>Tune Tunnels Alpha</title>
<head>
<!--=============================-->
<!-- Copy this part to your app. -->
<!-- START       -->
<!--=============================-->

<!-- libs -->
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="lib/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="raphael.js"></script> -->
<script src="closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>

<!-- box2djs -->
<script>
goog.addDependency('../common/b2Settings.js', ['box2d.Settings'], []);
goog.addDependency('../common/math/b2Vec2.js', ['box2d.Vec2'], []);
goog.addDependency('../common/math/b2Mat22.js', ['box2d.Mat22'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2Proxy.js', ['box2d.Proxy'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/ClipVertex.js', ['box2d.ClipVertex'], []);
goog.addDependency('../common/math/b2Math.js', ['box2d.Math'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2AABB.js', ['box2d.AABB'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2Bound.js', ['box2d.Bound'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2ShapeDef.js', ['box2d.ShapeDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2BoundValues.js', ['box2d.BoundValues'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2Pair.js', ['box2d.Pair'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2PairCallback.js', ['box2d.Callback'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2BufferedPair.js', ['box2d.BufferedPair'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2PairManager.js', ['box2d.PairManager'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2BroadPhase.js', ['box2d.BroadPhase'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2Collision.js', ['box2d.Collision'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/Features.js', ['box2d.Features'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2ContactID.js', ['box2d.ContactID'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2ContactPoint.js', ['box2d.ContactPoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2Distance.js', ['box2d.Distance'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2Manifold.js', ['box2d.Manifold'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/b2OBB.js', ['box2d.OBB'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2Shape.js', ['box2d.Shape'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2BoxDef.js', ['box2d.BoxDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2CircleDef.js', ['box2d.CircleDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2CircleShape.js', ['box2d.CircleShape'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2MassData.js', ['box2d.MassData'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2PolyDef.js', ['box2d.PolyDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../collision/shapes/b2PolyShape.js', ['box2d.PolyShape'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2Body.js', ['box2d.Body'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2BodyDef.js', ['box2d.BodyDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2CollisionFilter.js', ['box2d.CollisionFilter'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2Island.js', ['box2d.Island'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2TimeStep.js', ['box2d.TimeStep'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2ContactNode.js', ['box2d.ContactNode'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2Contact.js', ['box2d.Contact'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2ContactConstraint.js', ['box2d.ContactConstraint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2ContactConstraintPoint.js', ['box2d.ContactConstraintPoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2ContactRegister.js', ['box2d.ContactRegister'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2ContactSolver.js', ['box2d.ContactSolver'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2CircleContact.js', ['box2d.CircleContact'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2Conservative.js', ['box2d.Conservative'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2NullContact.js', ['box2d.NullContact'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2PolyAndCircleContact.js', ['box2d.PolyAndCircleContact'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/contacts/b2PolyContact.js', ['box2d.PolyContact'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2ContactManager.js', ['box2d.ContactManager'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2World.js', ['box2d.World'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/b2WorldListener.js', ['box2d.WorldListener'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2JointNode.js', ['box2d.JointNode'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2Joint.js', ['box2d.Joint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2JointDef.js', ['box2d.JointDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2DistanceJoint.js', ['box2d.DistanceJoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2DistanceJointDef.js', ['box2d.DistanceJointDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2Jacobian.js', ['box2d.Jacobian'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2GearJoint.js', ['box2d.GearJoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2GearJointDef.js', ['box2d.GearJointDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2MouseJoint.js', ['box2d.MouseJoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2MouseJointDef.js', ['box2d.MouseJointDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2PrismaticJoint.js', ['box2d.PrismaticJoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2PrismaticJointDef.js', ['box2d.PrismaticJointDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2PulleyJoint.js', ['box2d.PulleyJoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2PulleyJointDef.js', ['box2d.PulleyJointDef'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2RevoluteJoint.js', ['box2d.RevoluteJoint'], []);
goog.addDependency('../dynamics/joints/b2RevoluteJointDef.js', ['box2d.RevoluteJointDef'], []);
goog.require('goog.dom');
goog.require('box2d.Settings');
goog.require('box2d.Vec2');
goog.require('box2d.Mat22');
goog.require('box2d.Proxy');
goog.require('box2d.ClipVertex');
goog.require('box2d.Math');
goog.require('box2d.AABB');
goog.require('box2d.Bound');
goog.require('box2d.ShapeDef');
goog.require('box2d.RevoluteJoint');
goog.require('box2d.World')
goog.require('box2d.BoundValues');
goog.require('box2d.Pair');
goog.require('box2d.Callback');
goog.require('box2d.BufferedPair');
goog.require('box2d.PairManager');
goog.require('box2d.BroadPhase');
goog.require('box2d.Collision');
goog.require('box2d.Features');
goog.require('box2d.ContactID');
goog.require('box2d.ContactPoint');
goog.require('box2d.Distance');
goog.require('box2d.Manifold');
goog.require('box2d.OBB');
goog.require('box2d.Shape');
goog.require('box2d.BoxDef');
goog.require('box2d.CircleDef');
goog.require('box2d.CircleShape');
goog.require('box2d.MassData');
goog.require('box2d.PolyDef');
goog.require('box2d.PolyShape');
goog.require('box2d.Body');
goog.require('box2d.BodyDef');
goog.require('box2d.CollisionFilter')
goog.require('box2d.Island')
goog.require('box2d.TimeStep');
goog.require('box2d.ContactNode');
goog.require('box2d.Contact');
goog.require('box2d.ContactConstraint');
goog.require('box2d.ContactConstraintPoint');
goog.require('box2d.ContactRegister');
goog.require('box2d.ContactSolver');
goog.require('box2d.CircleContact');
goog.require('box2d.Conservative');
goog.require('box2d.NullContact');
goog.require('box2d.PolyAndCircleContact');
goog.require('box2d.PolyContact');
goog.require('box2d.ContactManager');
goog.require('box2d.WorldListener');
goog.require('box2d.JointNode');
goog.require('box2d.Joint');
goog.require('box2d.JointDef');
goog.require('box2d.DistanceJoint');
goog.require('box2d.DistanceJointDef');
goog.require('box2d.Jacobian');
goog.require('box2d.GearJoint');
goog.require('box2d.GearJointDef');
goog.require('box2d.MouseJoint');
goog.require('box2d.MouseJointDef');
goog.require('box2d.PrismaticJoint');
goog.require('box2d.PrismaticJointDef');
goog.require('box2d.PulleyJoint');
goog.require('box2d.PulleyJointDef');
goog.require('box2d.RevoluteJointDef');
</script>
        <!--=============================-->
        <!-- Copy this part to your app. -->
        <!-- END     -->
        <!--=============================-->
<link href="style/box2d.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var worldAABB = new b2AABB();
    worldAABB.minVertex.Set(-1000, -1000);
    worldAABB.maxVertex.Set(1000, 1000);
    var gravity = new b2Vec2(0, 300);
    var doSleep = true;
    var world = new b2World(worldAABB, gravity, doSleep); 
    var circleSd = new b2CircleDef();
    circleSd.density = 1.0;
    circleSd.radius = 20;
    circleSd.restitution = 1.0;
    circleSd.friction = 0;
    var circleBd = new b2BodyDef();
    circleBd.AddShape(circleSd);
    circleBd.position.Set(x,y);
    var circleBody = world.CreateBody(circleBd);

    var jointDef = new b2RevoluteJointDef();
    jointDef.anchorPoint.Set(250, 200);
    jointDef.body1 = world.GetGroundBody();
    jointDef.body2 = circleBody;
    world.CreateJoint(jointDef);
    var timeStep = 1.0/60;
    var iteration = 1;
    world.Step(timeStep, iteration);
    var ctx;
    var canvasWidth; 
    var canvasHeight; 
    function step(cnt) { 
        world.Step(1.0/60, 1);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        drawWorld(world, ctx); // see demos/draw_world.js
        setTimeout('step(' + (cnt || 0) + ')', 10);
    }
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        setupWorld(world); // as you like
        ctx = $('canvas').getContext('2d');
        var canvasElm = $('canvas');
        canvasWidth = parseInt(canvasElm.width);
        canvasHeight = parseInt(canvasElm.height);
        step();
    });
});
</script>
<canvas> </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, "which variable" on "which line"? Consider *remov[ing] all of the code but a minimal failing test-case*.

Comment: Also, it is generally good to avoid using the `setTimeout(string,...)` form in favor of `setTimeout(Function, ...)`.

Comment: var worldAABB = new b2AABB();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your closure/prototype environment, but since it looks like your JS files might be loading asynchronously, is it possible that all your JS files aren't loaded yet before the dom:loaded event fires:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    var worldAABB = new b2AABB();
```

The error is occurring on the first line of this function which is pretty suspicious.  Is there an event that fires when the JS files are all loaded?

So, I think you need to figure out whether this is a timing issue of script loading or whether it's a dependency problem and the desired scripts are never going to be loaded.  You can do that by temporarily replacing the entire `document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {` with a new function that just tests for the existence of b2AABB after a long timeout:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (b2AABB) {
      alert("Found it");
    } else {
      alert("Still not there");
    }
  }, 60 * 1000);  // wait 60 seconds
}
```

If it's still not present after 60 seconds, then it's probably never going to be available and you probably have a dependency issue.  If it is there after 60 seconds, then you probably have a timing issue.

Comment: What you're saying seems to be about it. The box2d JavaScript files need to be loaded and required before new b2AABB is called. Will check prototype to see if I can make sure the requires are loaded before Dom:loaded, but I thought that dim:loaded would come after the box2d lib files cuz each goog.require adds to the Dom.

Comment: The other option is that this is a closure error related to somehow loading the box2d libs wrong.

Comment: Scripts can be loaded long before the DOM is ready as JS can run in the <head> tag long before the <body> has finished loading so it makes sense to me that the two activities are not necessarily connected.  Google's module loader does know when a given script has finished loading - you just need to figure out how to get access to that info (I couldn't find it in my neophyte searches).

Comment: It turns out I have some MAJOR closure addDependency problems, apparently you have to declare the supporting requires in goog.addDependency, testing it out now.

Comment: Added a new suggestion onto the end of my previous answer to figure out if it's a timing or dependency issue.

Comment: Error appears to be due to complete absence of any documentation on the part of pixel lab. He changed the b2AABB to box2d.AABB however even changing script to this doesn't work. Also each js file needs a require statement so added those. Man this is really intricate especially for what's supposed to be a time saver. Going to email pixel lab for help.

Comment: Thanks fo the help, but I am pretty confident it's just a closure error and will TTY o run the closur builder when I get a chance.

Comment: If it's finally there after 60 seconds, then you can see why you need to actually compile all these scripts into one master script that will load a zillion times faster.

Comment: Yeah, I could understand that, it still isn't working, but I am down to some new errors now. Sadly I am sans laptop so compiling isn't really an option for me.