# Can't find variable: $

Tags: jscript

```
var scriptFile = $(tempNode).attr("customJScriptSrc");
```

When passing this i get

> “Reference Error: Can’t find variable: $”

Kindly suggest me any alternative methods.

Comment: have you include jquery in your page?

Comment: Please see similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555475/javascript-reference-error-cant-find-variable-plus-closure-blues

Comment: Be sure you load the jquery javascript file before the code that you posted.

Comment: Basically, `$` is not defined in your page. Why do you think it would be; did you include jQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add this script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

at top of the document(added before your javascript code).

or download the library and reference it in you code.

Comment: Also, it must be added before OP's script

Comment: Note that this assumes OP is not running from a local file (why not include `http:`?)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it was caused by me putting my .js file before the jQuery .js file in the DOM. This was causing an error because it was trying to read my .js file before recognizing that jQuery was even installed. Always put all your scripts in order of execution and alway at the very bottom of the `body` tag. This always makes sure that the page is fully loaded before trying to execute any javascript.

Before (Incorrect):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/rp-global.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

After (Correct):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/rp-global.js"></script>
```