# Need help to use .append() to a div element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using JQuery to use a variable `adj`, which contains several strings, but only use the string that is inside the variable of my choosing. I want to use this variable to use `.append()`  to create text inside `objective-container`  div element (ID).

I don’t know what’s wrong, but there is a error message which I don’t understand.

Error message:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
message: "Can't find variable: $"
line: 1
column: 2
sourceURL: "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1343EDD2-1DC1-4FCA-A570-8272D543005C/Documents/files/clicker/objectives/objScript.js"
stack: "global code@file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1343EDD2-1DC1-4FCA-A570-8272D543005C/Documents/files/clicker/objectives/objScript.js:1:2"
```

JS/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let obj = ["get points: 100",""];
  let currentObj = obj[0];
  let objective = "<div class=\"objective-text\"><p>" + currentObj + "</p></div>";
  // default
  $("#objective-container").append(objective); 
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="objective-container" class="objectiveContainer">
      <!—- objectives go here -—>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't included jquery.js `<script>` before your script.  See (of many) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46938820/2181514

Comment: Have you used jquery script tag in your html head? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: off-topic: mix and match `'` and `"` so you don't need to use `\"`, eg: `"<div class='objective-text'>.."` or `'<div class="objective-text">..'`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this error shows us that the HTML *you desire* is not rendering properly because it can't find `$`, which it's interpreted as an attribute. In order to use it as a jQuery notation, you must include it through a `script` tag or jQuery methods won't run.

So make sure you put the version you want inside your html head tag:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Improvement: use template string to insert directly `currentObj` inside `objective`

---

Now the code below works properly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let obj = ["get points: 100",""];
  let currentObj = obj[0];
  let objective = `<div class='objective-text'><p>${currentObj}</p></div>`;
  // default
  $("#objective-container").append(objective); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- meta tags -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="objective-container" class="objectiveContainer">
      <!—- objectives go here -—>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Missing a script tag makes _his code_ not render as expected (not properly)

Comment: I let you improve my answer, you are able. Aren't you?

Comment: I'm not against anything. I just want to understand your POV/reasons or you can simply edit directly. I'm open to improvements, learning every day

Comment: Here's my answer: Does this answer your question? [Can't find variable: $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889985/cant-find-variable/46938820#46938820) - voted close

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me, looks like it just doesn't recognise the $ variable, which is just a pointer to jQuery. Make sure you have included the jQuery library on the HTML page like so.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```